# valores hexadecimales

Tags: php

Quiero realizar una operación entre hexadecimales.

Tengo un paquete de datos que viene en forma de **base64**, lo paso a **hexadecimal** a traves del uso de ***bin2hex***:

```
 $hex = bin2hex(base64_decode($dato));
```

El problema es que después de hacer esto la variable `$hex` tiene el siguiente valor:

> 170d8600630139

Para operarlo en la funcion que necesito realizar es necesario que empiece con el prefijo de hexadecimal `0x`

osea que quede asi:

> 0x170d8600630139

¿Alguien sabe como puedo dejarlo de esta manera?

Concatenado ahora el valor es **'0x170d8600630139'** pero sin embargo no me deja operarlo porque lo reconoce como cadena.

¿Alguna solución ?

Answer (score 6):

Podes concatenarle lo que queres con el operador `.` (punto)

Guardas en una variable el valor `0x` (que es el que te falta), y luego de usar `bin2hex` le concatenas este valor con el operador antes mencionado

```
<?php
   $hex = 170d8600630139
   $a = "0x";
   $hex = $a.$hex
?>
```

> > Ahora $hex es '0x170d8600630139'

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvio